# My program does everything correctly, except it prints out the input in a randomized order [Python 3, Beginner]

Tags: python, sorting, random, python-3.x

```
input1 = input("Corrupted: ")
input2 = ""
final = ""
for i in input1:
  if i in "ATGC ":
    input2 = input2 + i
for i in set(input2.split()):
  final = final + i + " "
print("DNA:",final.rstrip())
```

The aim of this program is to allow the user to enter a string of text, with a DNA code hidden inside. This program extracts the DNA code (basically, anything that is not ATCG). It also removes duplicate entires. It does everthing correct but it prints out the question in an incorrect order. I'd ask my tutor for help but he is currently unable to assist me.

```
Corrupted: A1TGcC A?T-G %^AT@CT ATGc #Notice the double ATG (2nd and last one)
DNA: ATGC ATCT ATG #Only one ATG since one is removed.
```

when it was meant to output:

```
Corrupted: A1TGcC A?T-G %^AT@CT ATGc #This one is in the correct order. How do I get it to stay in the same order?
DNA: ATGC ATG ATCT
```

Comment: Sets are not ordered; use a list instead perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets don't have any order:

```
>>> print(set.__doc__)
...
Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
```

To preserve the order you can do something like:

```
>>> lis = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [item for item in lis if item not in seen and not seen.add(item)]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

For your code instead of string concatenation you can use `regex` because something like `input2 = input2 + i` is going to be [very slow for large strings](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation).

```
>>> import re
>>> corruped = 'A1TGcC A?T-G %^AT@CT ATGc'
>>> lis = re.sub('[^ATGC\s]', '', corruped).split()
>>> lis
['ATGC', 'ATG', 'ATCT', 'ATG']
```

Comment: @R337 No need of sorry, at least you tried something.(most beginners just ask for code) ;-)